# How to test for mass assignment error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, mass-assignment

Seems I want to do the opposite of what most people ask for when testing rails...

How to test FOR ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error.  I get this already, just want to know how to make it make my test case green and not red.

current test:

```
describe Tag do
  let(:tag) { FactoryGirl.create(:tag) }
  subject { tag }

  describe "when tag name is sent directly" do
    before { tag = Tag.new(name: "New") } # <- what I want to raise the error
    it { should_not be_valid } # <- doesn't make it to this line
  end
end
```

How should I structure this as a proper test?  I have tried:

```
    lambda do
      tag = Tag.new(name: "NEW")
    end.should raise_error
```

But that doesn't work for me either, I get

```
Exception encountered: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `raise_error' for #<Class:0x00000102525c08>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah, had to put it inside an it {}:

```
it do
  lambda { tag = Tag.new(name: "NEW") }.should raise_error
end
```

This solved the problem for me